# Type reference scope

Tags: oracle, scope, types, constraints, ref

I'm studying databases and am currently working on a object-relational DB project and I've encountered a small problem with the number of possible constraints in an object table. I'm using "Database Systems: The Complete Book" by Hector Garcia-Molina (and other authors) as a reference and there's a general SQL example like this:

```
CREATE TYPE StarType AS (
  name CHAR(30),
  address AddressType,
  bestMovie REF(MovieType) SCOPE Movies
);
```

Now, I have a kind of a similar type in my project, as it also uses reference to another type within a type, but the clause for placing a reference there doesn't include SCOPE in Oracle (at least I haven't found it in the docs and it outputs an error). So I have a type like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "ApplicationType" AS OBJECT (
  "person" REF "PersonType",
  "competition" REF "CompetitionType",
  "dateApplied" DATE
);
/
```

...which works. But when I want to constrain the REF columns, I can constrain only one, as so:

```
CREATE TABLE "Applications" OF "ApplicationType" (
  "person" SCOPE IS "People" /* or "competition" SCOPE IS "Competitions" */
)
OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;
```

Is there any way to give constraints to both REF columns?

Comment: What happens when you try both? What error message do you get?

Comment: I get the "ORA-00904: : invalid identifier" error. But when I use either one of those constraints alone, the table creates normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
CREATE TABLE Applications OF ApplicationType (
  person SCOPE IS People,
  competition SCOPE IS Competitions
)
OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;
```

Maybe you tried creating the table using `or` instead of `,` for separating the constraints(as seen in your comment).

It's also easy to test your constraints. Just create these two additional dummy tables:

```
CREATE TABLE People2 OF PersonType
OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;

CREATE TABLE Competitions2 OF CompetitionType
OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO People VALUES('p1');
INSERT INTO People2 VALUES('p21');
INSERT INTO Competitions VALUES('c1');
INSERT INTO Competitions2 VALUES('c21');
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO Applications
VALUES
(
   (SELECT REF(p) FROM People p WHERE person = 'p1'),
   (SELECT REF(c) FROM Competitions2 c WHERE competition = 'c21'),
   SYSDATE
);
```

results in an ORA-22889 since the refered value is not in the specified scoped table(which is Competitions, not the dummy Competitions2).
You can test similarly using People2 instead of People.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Marius. I didn't user "or" when I got that error, my code looked exactly as yours (except I had table, type and attribute names surrounded with ""). I tried again, created all the types and tables again, but it still doesn't work for me, even without the "" (although it shouldn't have anything to do with it)? my code looks exactly as yours.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire SQL(CREATE TYPE/TABLE, INSERTS etc.) you use so that I can have a look at it.

Comment: I just reviewed my code again, I had a silly typo error in my CREATE TABLE statement, there was a coma at the end of the last constraint which produced the SQL error. It works now. :) Thank you for your help and suggestions for constraint testing!